# Technique for dynamically changing form field labels based on the selected value of a form element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a relatively simple HTML / JavaScript form.  Such as this:

```
<form method='POST' action='someurl'>
    <label for='field1'>Your name</label>
    <input id='field1' name='field1' type='text' />

    <label for='field2'>Status</label>
    <select id='field2' name='field2'>
        <option>-select one-</option>
        <option value='Employee'>Employee</option>
        <option value='Retiree'>Retiree</option>
    </select>

    <label for='field3'>City you work in</label>
    <input id='field3' name='field3' type='text' />
</form>
```

What I need to be able to do, is change the text inside of the label for field3 based on the selected value in field2.  So when field2 has 'Employee' selected the field3 label says 'City you work in', but when field2 has 'Retiree' selected then field3's label should be 'City where you live'.

One solution I have done is to have multiple  tags inside of the field3 label, and then using some JavaScript I can toggle which of the  tags inside the label is being displayed, like this:

```
// Form as above
<label for='field3'>
    <span id='field3EmployeeLabel' style='display:none;'>City you work in</span>
    <span id='field3RetireeLabel' style='display:none;'>City where you live</span>
</label>
<input id='field3' name='field3' type='text' />

function updateLabel() {
    if($('#field2').val()=='Employee') {
        $('#field3RetireeLabel').hide();
        $('#field3EmployeeLabel').show();
    } 
    else if($('#field2').val()=='Retiree') {
        $('#field3EmployeeLabel').hide();
        $('#field3RetireeLabel').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#field3RetireeLabel').hide();
        $('#field3EmployeeLabel').show();       
    }
}
```

The main reason that I don't like this is that it all has to be coded by hand, and this is just a simple example, what if there are 7 or 8 different options in field2?  Also, what if I had to combine multiple form field values to figure out which label to display?

Is there a design pattern or best-practice for this sort of thing in HTML?  How have others handled this sort of requirement on their forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a map of values to labels to display http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/VBVtE/3/ When you add new options, just add them to the labels map.

**JS**

```
$('#field2').change(function() {
    var labels = {
        'Employee' : 'City you work in',
        'Retiree' : 'City you live in',
        '-select one-': 'Default value'
    }      
    $("label[for='field3']").html(labels[$(this).val()]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would probably solve it a bit like this (in an isolated scope, of course):

```
var labelEl = $( "label[ for='field3' ]" ),
    labels  = { Employee : "City in which you work",
                Retiree  : "City where you live"
              }
;

$('#field2').change( function() {
  // choose the correct label (default to the Employee label)
  var newLabel = labels[ $(this).val() ] || labels.Employee;

  labelEl.text( newLabel ); // change the label text
} );
```

The function could obviously be reduced to a one-liner, avoiding the creation of `newLabel`, but I've left it as-is for readability.

Comment: the line that is trying to default it to Employee won't work, the value of the select field is '-select one-' when you choose that option

Comment: You're creating globals so you don't have to reinstantiate the map and the element with every change. The globals are only needed by the handler, they should not be globals. An easy way to address this is to wrap everything in a `$(function(){})` But I particularly think it's premature optimization and detracts from what the question is asking, and potentially leads the OP to pollute the global scope

Comment: It's my assumption that the OP is using this code within e.g. a `jQuery.ready()` block, as you suggest.

Comment: But the problem I'm talking about requires that this be the only code within the `jQuery.ready` function. No other function should have access to those variables

Comment: The problem you were talking about was polluting the global scope, but now you're talking about polluting the scope of `jQuery.ready` (which, incidentally, can be called multiple times). If you're going to do this kind of scope-gardening–the height of prematurity, IMO—you shouldn't be declaring application code in `ready` anyway.

Comment: I am suggesting that if you're going to do this, it should be in its own `jQuery.ready` so that no other code has access to the variables. I never heard of *scope-gardening* and didn't find a good hit on google. Also don't see what you mean by height of prematurity. Where do you declare your application code, if not within a `$.ready`?

Comment: Any substantial amount of client-side code should be encapsulated as separate modules (probably in different files, though they may be concatenated in your build/deploy process). Just like a constructor in OOP or `main` in a Java app, `$.ready` should be used for initialization only, and at that only for code that actually needs to wait for the DOM.

Comment: IMO, jQuery is not really meant for large-scale OO development. For full OO development you would be using something like dojo, Ext-JS, backbone or something that provides a framework for creating MVC components.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I would suggest is the following:

```html
<label id="label3" for="field3">
  <span id="label3_Employee">City you work in</span>
  <span id="label3_Retiree">City you live in</span>
</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateLabel() {
    $('label#label3 span').hide();
    $('label#label3 span#label3_' + $('#field2').val()).show();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of @Juan and @Jordan's answers: (both of which are great, thanks!)

```
$('#field2').change(function() {
    var labels = {
        'Employee' : 'City you work in',
        'Retiree' : 'City you live in',
        'default': 'Default value'
    }      
    $("label[for='field3']").html(labels[$(this).val()] || labels['default']);
});
```

This allows for the field to have a default value without having to specifically designate each possible option in the labels list, all I need to specify are the cases that differ from the default.

Comment: This doesn't add much to what we already suggested, does it? You should accept either of those answers.